# Change SVG stroke options in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, svg, graphics, charts, highcharts

Is there any easy way of customizing the way Highcharts renders lines?

I'm not talking about colors or with (part of the API) but things like stroke-linejoin or stroke-linecap.

Basically, I'd like to change the values from 'round' to 'mitel'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it's not supported. However, you can achieve that by wrapping `drawGraph` method, for example:

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.line.prototype, 'drawGraph', function (p) {
    var series = this,
        options = this.options,
        props = [
            ['graph', options.lineColor || this.color]
        ];

    p.call(series);

    H.each(props, function (prop, i) {
        var graphKey = prop[0],
            graph = series[graphKey];

        if (graph) {
            graph.attr({
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                    'stroke-linecap': 'square'
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v7h622c0/